# Video download with php curl

Tags: php, curl

I have to download large videos with curl. Cause the site where I download from put 403 blocks, And I can pass thru with only Curl. Thats my php curl function code. I need this with the download but it shouldnt eat up my memory..

```
function fakeip()
{
//return long2ip( mt_rand(0, 65537) * mt_rand(0, 65535) ); 
return "127.0.0.1";
}
    function curlx($feed,$coo=null,$ref=null)
{

        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 0;
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: ".fakeip(),"X-Client-IP: ".fakeip(),"Client-IP: ".fakeip(),"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: ".fakeip(),"X-Forwarded-For: ".fakeip()));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0');
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "88.150.225.55");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
        if(!empty($coo))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $coo);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $coo);
        }
        if(empty($ref))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,$feed);
        }
        else
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,$ref);
        }
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $veri= curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
         return str_replace(array("\n", "\t", "\r",), null, $veri); 
}
```

Comment: To confirm, you are saying your current code works but uses too much memory?

Comment: Set `CURLOPT_FILE` to let cURL save the response into a file (you need to pass a  `fopen` handler) instead of into memory.

Comment: Charlotte, please you can edit my code and answer your version of code... Chris, no, this function code made for get the web pages (like file_get_content), I need similar of this code (Becouse every curl code couldnt pass thru to block), but for the video downloads not get web pages and I know some curl codes when trying to download it uses too much memory thats what I added this request...

Comment: You might want to check this API:  https://weibomiaopai.com/download-video-parser.php